# Where does the quote about the 'Super Slammer' trap in Ghostbusters The Video Game come from, can it actually store multiple ghosts?

Tags: ghostbusters

Several unofficial wikis and walkthroughs I've checked contained the text:

> The Super Slammer utilizes the same technology as the new and improved
> Muon Ghost Trap, but it's more advanced and powerful in many ways.
> Just like the Muon Ghost Trap, the Super Slammer is also able to
> compartmentalize each captured P.K.E. manifestation into an infinite
> number of artificially induced dimensioned "pockets" of reality within
> the trap, but faster and more efficiently than a regular trap.
> Allowing for continuous re-use and multiple, instantiated captures of
> ghosts without worrying that the trap will get too full or need to be
> emptied immediately.

But they don't seem to reference anything official to back this up - was this just made up and copied all over the internet?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.   Just to check, you're not actually asking how it works, you're asking if the given description has an authoritative source, correct?

Comment: @DavidW - I'm pretty sure that OP is trying to source the references for some of these statement. They appear to be referring to the [GB Wiki article on the super-slammer](https://ghostbusters.fandom.com/wiki/Super_Slammer_Muon_Trap) which indicates where some of the info comes from, but not all of it.

Comment: @DavidW I'm pretty sure how it works is "game logic", but I am interested if there's an official explanation. This unsourced explanation is muddying the waters. I've seen it repeated verbatim in several walkthroughs, for example IGN's, but the wikis have references to other parts of the statement but not the quoted part.